# Summing A Range of Correct Matches Against Another Range

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

I have found similar posts but cant seem to get anything to work for me. Ive seen stuff like arrays but I have no clue how that works.

long story short amongst friends we started a FIFA world cup pool. We all have our answers (H, A, or D) and Im looking for a formula that will sum the correct answers for each player.

Heres a small example.

[image]

Since my knowledge is limited to basic functions like `=sum(a1:a10)` I'm unable to figure this one out because i'm comparing letters instead of numbers.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: You're making it too complicated.  Look up on google or youtube how to sum a range of cells.

Comment: heres a copy of the spreadsheet. I dont think you understand that a sum of range isnt exactly what im looking for because im dealing with letters instead of numbers and when I tried the sumproduct value it just like multiplies or something.

Essentially, if the result of game 1 is draw or D then whoever guessed D in column G would get 1 point. so on and so forth adding up the total points at the end.

 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZNo3dBGhr0YkNjYgIOqja94XfEYUi7I6dv6BDz4C150/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your results (`key`) displayed vertically while predictions are horizontal is likely your issue. This can be fixed using the [Transpose Function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/transpose-function/). Combining `Transpose` with with any of the below methods returns the correct value of `21` successful predictions for `Player 2` (I tested on your sheet).

- `=Sum(ARRAYFORMULA(--(G3:BB3=transpose(KEY))))`
- `=Sum(ARRAYFORMULA(if(G3:BB3=transpose(KEY),1,0)))`
- `=Counta(FILTER(G3:BB3,G3:BB3=transpose(KEY)))`
- `=SUMPRODUCT(G3:BB3=transpose(KEY))`

Comment: You sir are a genius.... If only i knew this much..Thank you! 

I need to find me some courses because I would love to be able to know how to do all these types of formulas and more.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. There's literally thousands of YouTube channels out there begging for you to watch them all they ask is for a LIKE. There's lots of good questions on Stack Overflow too. [Player()](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) is probably the most queen of such array/summation formulas. Looking through a lot of her answers you'll find a lot of stuff. Filter is my go to formula. Play with that enough and you'll be good.